# Flash transparent background not working on Mac

Tags: flash, macos, firefox, safari, transparency

Hi I just can't seem to get the background to be transparent on a Mac, see here: http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/smokinhot/templates/smokinhot/

I'm using wmode=transparent. I've been searching google for ages and see that wmode is not very stable and that it will work if I use the 'embed' tag but it would not be valid code anymore.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that your background position is static you could skip the transparent background and just add that part of the image in the flash. You will need to pull some other tricks to get the position exactly right across browsers, but it will work better and improve performance.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't though of that. I suppose it's not the ideal solution but seems to be the only one! Many thanks indeed :)